# javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded DES

Tags: java, des

I get error when I try to decode. 
This is Decoder:

```
public class Encrypter {

    Cipher ecipher;
    Cipher dcipher;

    SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec("missyou1".getBytes(), "DES");

    public DesEncrypter() throws Exception {
        ecipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
        dcipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
        ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
    }

    public String encrypt(String str) throws Exception {
        byte[] utf8 = str.getBytes("UTF8");
        byte[] enc = ecipher.doFinal(utf8);
        return new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(enc);
    }

    public String decrypt(String str) throws Exception {
        byte[] dec = new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(str);

        byte[] asd = new byte[(dec.length/8+1)*8];
        for(int i = 0; i < dec.length; i++){
            asd[i] = dec[i];
        }
        byte[] utf8 = dcipher.doFinal(asd);

        return new String(utf8, "UTF8");
    }
}
```

This is code where I get error:

```
private static void appenda(Encrypter encrypt) {
        if (Files.exists(Paths.get(filePath), new LinkOption[] { LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS })) {
            Stream<String> stringStream = null;
            try {
                stringStream = Files.lines(Paths.get(filePath), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                LOGGER.error("Failed ", e);
            }

            if (stringStream.toString() != null) {
                stringStream.forEach(s -> {
                    try {
                        System.out.println(encrypt.decrypt(s));
                        endpoint.delete(0, endpoint.length());
                        endpoint.append(encrypt.decrypt(s));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        LOGGER.error("Failed to decrypt", e);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

in line `endpoint.append(encrypter.decrypt(s));`
Any idea why?

Comment: DES should not be used in new work, it is not secure and has been superceeded by AES.

Answer (score 0):

Its not working because you are needlessly copying the data into an incorrectly sized array.

Just remove the array copy and decrypt the bytes directly.

```
public String decrypt(String str) throws Exception {
    byte[] dec = new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(str);
    byte[] utf8 = dcipher.doFinal(dec);
    return new String(utf8, "UTF8");
}
```